# ddSlick included but doesn't work

Tags: php, jquery, html, laravel, laravel-blade

Hi I'm trying to make a dropdown with images. And that's why I want to use ddSlick (a jQuery plugin), which can realize that for me. Unfortunately it doesn't work. But I have followed the instructions of the plugin. I have tried the following:

template_head.blade.php (which includes the jquery.ddslick.min.js file)

```
 <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <title>Offerte tool</title>
      <!-- Bootstrap -->
      {{HTML::style('css/bootstrap.min.css')}}
      <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
      {{ HTML::script('js/bootstrap.min.js') }}
      <!-- To use less I have to include my own css first and then the less library. Because I have read the following in less.org:Make sure you include your stylesheets before the script.) -->
      <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('css/core.less') }}" />

      <script src="{{ asset('js/less-1.7.5.min.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="{{ asset('js/bootstrap-rating-input.min.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="{{ asset('js/jquery.ddslick.min.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
       {{HTML::script('js/application.js')}}
```

user.blade.php (which has a dropdown list)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
    @include('user._layouts.template_head')
   </head>
    <script>
      $('#myDropdown').ddslick({
    onSelected: function(selectedData){
        //callback function: do something with selectedData;
         $('#demo-htmlselect').ddslick();
      }   
    });
    </script>

   <body>
      <select id="demo-htmlselect">
        <option value="0" data-imagesrc="{{ asset('images/orange.png') }}"
            data-description="Description with Facebook">Facebook</option>
        <option value="1" data-imagesrc="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40036711/Images/twitter-icon-32.png"
            data-description="Description with Twitter">Twitter</option>
        <option value="2"  data-imagesrc="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40036711/Images/linkedin-icon-32.png"
            data-description="Description with LinkedIn">LinkedIn</option>
        <option value="3" data-imagesrc="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40036711/Images/foursquare-icon-32.png"
            data-description="Description with Foursquare">Foursquare</option>
    </select>
   </body>
</html>
```

In user.blade.php you can see the following:

```
  <option value="0" data-imagesrc="{{ asset('images/orange.png') }}"
```

So can you see I have a image that should show in the dropdownlist. But it doesn't as you can see here:

link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uBjc.png

The image orange.png looks like this:

link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1PfiP.png

I have also tested if my webapplication makes a connection with the jquery.ddslick.min.js file. And it does make a connection. Here you can see a screenshot of it:

link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/43Kv1.png

Could someone help me, please? I'm waiting for your response. Anyway thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a wild guess, but you probably need to wrap your js code in `$(document).ready()`.
This ensures that all the element's in the DOM exist and the plugin can get initialized correctly.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#demo-htmlselect').ddslick();
});
```

**Edit:** also you don't need all the `#myDropdown` stuff

Comment: Hi I have tried your solution, but unfortunately it didn't work :(.

Comment: @superkytoz ok, why exactly do you initialize the ddslick on the `#demo-htmlselect` in the callback function of `#myDropdown`?

Comment: To actually be honest I don't know, but I have tried this now: link: http://pastebin.com/Sc4aVGWE  but it still doesn't work.. I use this code, because I have read it from the instructions on link: http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/ddSlick

Comment: The selector (`#myDropdown`) does need to match your select element. give me a sec I'll update my answer

Comment: I'm so happy it works! Again thanks for your answer :)!

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
  $('#demo-htmlselect').ddslick({
onSelected: function(selectedData){
    //callback function: do something with selectedData;
     $('#demo-htmlselect').ddslick();
  }   
});
</script>
```

You need to give your dropdown id instead of `myDropdown`. then in `onSelected`function you can do manipulations with the selected data if you want.